# Dynamically adding an ActiveX control to VB.Net form does nothing

Tags: vb.net, activex, quicktime

In VB.Net, I'm trying to add a QuickTime ActiveX control to a Form when the user clicks a button.

My code is below. For testing I've got a design-time ActiveX control, "designed_control", which works fine, but I'm trying to place "dynamically_created_control" onto the form.

```
Public Class Form1

Private moviePath As String = "\\localhost\D$\Temp\Test.mov"
Friend WithEvents dynamically_created_control As AxQTOControlLib.AxQTControl = Nothing

Private Sub buttonLoadMovieIntoExisting_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonLoadMovieIntoExisting.Click
    ' load movie into control created in designer, works fine:
    MessageBox.Show(moviePath)
    With designed_control
        .URL = moviePath
        MessageBox.Show("URL:" + .URL)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub buttonCreateNewControl_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonCreateNewControl.Click
    ' create a new ActiveX control when button is clicked:
    dynamically_created_control = New AxQTOControlLib.AxQTControl
    CType(dynamically_created_control, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(Form1))
    With dynamically_created_control
        .CreateControl()
        .Enabled = True
        .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(160, 160)
        .Name = "new_control"
        .OcxState = CType(resources.GetObject("designed_control.OcxState"), System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)
        .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(480, 270)
        .TabIndex = 0
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.dynamically_created_control)
        .Visible = True
        .URL = moviePath
    End With
    CType(dynamically_created_control, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    Me.ResumeLayout(True)
    With dynamically_created_control
        MessageBox.Show("URL:" + vbCrLf + .URL)
        .Movie.Play()
    End With
End Sub

End Class
```

This doesn't work; when I click 'buttonCreateNewControl', it will pop up the 'URL:' messagebox with the correct URL, showing that the properties of dynamically_created_control are being set and the object is not nothing. However the rectangular shape of the control I'd expect doesn't appear on the form. As soon as I call the .Play() method of the control, it raises an exception because .Movie is nothing, when it shouldn't be.

Can anyone spot why the dynamically-generated ActiveX control simply doesn't appear (but without throwing errors), when the designer-based version is absolutely fine?

Incidentally, I'm aware of the security issues around QuickTime, which is why I'm now trying to code something which can *optionally* use QuickTime if the user decides to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may need to update buttonCreateNewControl_Click to use

```
    .OcxState = CType(resources.GetObject("dynamically_created_control.OcxState"), System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this change does not affect the result. The information about using the ocxState from a different control is from here: http://www.softelvdm.com/Support/NETDynamicallyCreatedControls/tabid/150/ . The fact your suggested change makes no difference makes me think that this line of code, setting the OcxState, may still be the problem, but I don't know how to set a new OcxState correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have spotted the error in my code.

The .createControl() method was attempting to create an external QuickTime window. That control works for something like VLC Player, but QuickTime doesn't support it, so nothing was happening.

As soon as I commented out createControl(), the behaviour became what I was expecting.

The .createControl() was a leftover from code I found online, I assumed it was essential for initiating the ActiveX control but it isn't.